# Why is append() slower than + and is there some oversight in the map() solution which slows it down?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I was trying out some variation in implementation of a leetcode example and was surprised by the runtimes. I was expecting it would be better to use `map()` than classic grandpa style `for`-loop

In short the problem is to find if a value in the list is smaller or larger than a threshold value

https://leetcode.com/problems/kids-with-the-greatest-number-of-candies/submissions/

### Here are the three implementations:

### 72 ms 13.8 MB

Map over the input list and generate the list of bool

```
class Solution:
    def kidsWithCandies(self, candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:

        m=max(candies)-extraCandies
        return list(map( lambda x: x>=m, candies))
```

### 40 ms 14 MB

For-loop and `append()` to list

```
class Solution:
    def kidsWithCandies(self, candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:

        m=max(candies)-extraCandies
        ans=[]
        for x in candies:
            ans.append(x>=m)
        return ans
```

### 28 ms 13.6 MB

Use `+` to append to list

```
class Solution:
    def kidsWithCandies(self, candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:

        m=max(candies)-extraCandies
        ans=[]
        for x in candies:
            ans+=[(x>=m)]
        return ans
```

Why is `append()` slower than `+` and is there some oversight in the `map()` solution which slows it down?

Comment: In addition you might try to resize the list to a proper size at start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask whether there is an oversight in the `map` solution, slowing it down.
There is, in the form of `lambda`.
When passing `lambda` objects, `map` is slowed down, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948713/11477374).
Passing proper function objects does not have the same restrictions.

Other than that, I was unable to confirm the large performance discrepancy you found between `append` (40ms) and `__iadd__`/`+=` (28ms).
In the below tests, `append` is *faster* than `+=` by (just) about 2 percent.
That is negligible.

Below, five versions of your function are tested.
Next to `kidsWithCandies_map_builtin`, which uses the `ge` function of the `operator` module to get a `callable` `ge(a, b)` that returns the same as `a >= b`, the arguably most Pythonic approach is also tested, list comprehension.

```py
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from operator import ge
from pprint import pprint as pp
from timeit import timeit
from typing import List

candy_distribution = namedtuple(
    "CandyDistribution", ["candies", "extra_candies", "solution"]
)

candy_distributions = [
    candy_distribution([2, 3, 5, 1, 3], 3, [True, True, True, False, True]),
    candy_distribution([4, 2, 1, 1, 2], 1, [True, False, False, False, False]),
    candy_distribution([12, 1, 12], 10, [True, False, True]),
]


def kidsWithCandies_map_lambda(candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:

    threshold = max(candies) - extraCandies
    return list(map(lambda x: x >= threshold, candies))


def kidsWithCandies_map_builtin(candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:

    threshold = max(candies) - extraCandies
    thresholds = [threshold] * len(candies)
    return list(map(ge, candies, thresholds))


def kidsWithCandies_append(candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:

    threshold = max(candies) - extraCandies
    ans = []
    for x in candies:
        ans.append(x >= threshold)
    return ans


def kidsWithCandies_iadd(candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:

    threshold = max(candies) - extraCandies
    ans = []
    for x in candies:
        ans += [(x >= threshold)]
    return ans


def kidsWithCandies_comprehension(candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:

    threshold = max(candies) - extraCandies
    return [element >= threshold for element in candies]


functions_to_runtimes = defaultdict(int)


for func in (
    kidsWithCandies_map_lambda,
    kidsWithCandies_map_builtin,
    kidsWithCandies_append,
    kidsWithCandies_iadd,
    kidsWithCandies_comprehension,
):
    for candy_supply in candy_distributions:
        args = (candy_supply.candies, candy_supply.extra_candies)
        assert candy_supply.solution == func(*args)
        functions_to_runtimes[func.__name__] += timeit("func(*args)", globals=globals())

functions_to_runtimes = {  # sort by value, ascending
    k: v for k, v in sorted(functions_to_runtimes.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
}

pp(functions_to_runtimes)
```

with an output of

```py
{'kidsWithCandies_append': 2.2671058810083196,
 'kidsWithCandies_comprehension': 2.3766544990066905,
 'kidsWithCandies_iadd': 2.3180257579660974,
 'kidsWithCandies_map_builtin': 2.9652103499975055,
 'kidsWithCandies_map_lambda': 3.658640267996816}
```

So while there is not much of a difference between `append`, `comprehension` and in-place addition (`+=`), `map` is much improved by *not* using a lambda.

The most non-grandpa style approach is the list comprehension. `map` was even originally supposed to be [dropped from Python 3](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196); as such (but this is speculation), one can suspect that all the performance love and care went towards (list) comprehensions, `append` and `+=`. Others have tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407222/11477374), but `map`, as a built-in, seems hard to introspect.

I omitted space complexity considerations because these seem similar for all approaches.